# Stop PhpStorm from aligning associative arrays

Tags: coding-style, phpstorm

How can I tell PhpStorm (using version 8.0.3) to keep the following array as is when clicking `Cmd+Alt+L` to reformat my code:

```
$array = [
    'short' => 1, // I want this...
    'veryVeryVeryIncrediblyLong' => 123456789,
];
```

Instead of doing this:

```
$array = [
    'short'                      => 1, // Not this...
    'veryVeryVeryIncrediblyLong' => 123456789,
];
```

Comment: 1) And by "aligned" you mean multiple lines aligned by `=>` characters? (better post aligned version as well, to be 100% clear). 2) Always state your PhpStorm version.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

**Since PhpStorm 2017.x version** the appropriate option is located at:

- `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Code Style`
- `PHP | Wrapping and Braces`
- `Array initializer | Align key-value pairs`

[image]

---

##### ORIGINAL ANSWER (for v2016 and older)

- `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Code Style | PHP`
- `Other | Array declaration style -> Align key-value pairs`

[image]

Comment: I just created an issue on this see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-30571  . Align key-value pairs does not work on 10.0.3

Answer (score 55):

In **Phpstorm 2017.3 & later**  , This setting is located at
 **File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces | Array initializer | Align key-value pairs**

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Preferences → Editor → Code Style → PHP → Other → Align key-value pairs

[image]

Answer (score 3):

PhpStorm 2019 and up: Settings -> editor -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces -> Array initializer -> Align key-value pairs [*] (Linux OS)

[image: PhpStorm 2019 and up]

Answer (score 2):

In phpstorm 2019 it goes somewhere like this:
(settings > editor > php > Wrapping and Braces > Assignment statement > Align consecutive assignments)
[PHPStorm 9 align assignments in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787223/phpstorm-9-align-assignments-in-php/32789622)