# PhpStorm / IntelliJ make array assignments align

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have this code:

```
$this->viewData = [
    'user' => $this->user,
    'donor' => $this->donor,
    'cause' => null,
    'donation' => null,
    'autologin_url' => $autologin_url,
];
```

I want all `=>` to be aligned. Can I set that somewhere?

E.g. I want it to look something like this

```
$this->viewData = [
  'user'             => $this->user,
  'donor'            => $this->donor,
  'cause'            => null,
  'donation'         => null,
];
```

Comment: Inversely relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795116/stop-phpstorm-from-aligning-associative-arrays

Comment: Just as Carcigenicate said -- do the opposite (enable option) in that linked question/answer.

Comment: wow that was it, thanks. you can write it as answer