# How can I align different lines in PHP code?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

PhpStorm 2021.2:

```
            $is_fullcalendar_nearest_days =  $expireDateCheckNearest->isPast();
            return [
                'id'               => 'ad' . $adItem->id,
                'title'            => $adItem->id . '=>' . $adItem->title,
                'adLocationsCount'   => $adItem->ad_locations_count,
                'status'           => $adItem->status,
                'status_label'     => Ad::getStatusLabel($adItem->status),
                'ad_type'       => $adItem->ad_type,
                'ad_type_label' => Ad::getAdTypeLabel($adItem->ad_type),
                'price'       => $adItem->price,
                'price_formatted' => formatCurrencySum($adItem->price),
                'is_fullcalendar_nearest_days' => $is_fullcalendar_nearest_days,
            ];
```

How can I align lines above with all `=>` and `=` at same level?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29795404/783119 for array elements alignment.

Comment: **Consecutive assignments** can also be aligned on `=` sign -- https://i.imgur.com/hgnaDfY.png (an empty line or a comment between lines works as a "group separator"

Comment: But if you want the WHOLE code sample to be aligned on `=` (both assignment statement and array elements in the `return`) .. then **String Manipulation plugin** can do such stuff and much more (can align selected lines on specific delimiter symbol): https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation