# PhpStorm reformat array

Tags: php, phpstorm, code-formatting

I lost my previous settings from PhpStorm for formatting an array like this:

```php
$array = [
    'short_key' => 'value1',
    'a_much_longer_key' => 'value2',
    'another_long_key' => 'value3',
];
```

by hitting <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> it would become like this:

```php
$array = [
    'short_key'         => 'value1',
    'a_much_longer_key' => 'value2',
    'another_long_key'  => 'value3',
];
```

How is this setting called? How to make PhpStorm do this? It has to be somewhere under "Settings -> Code Style".

Comment: "Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces | Array initializer | Align key-value pairs". Here it was asked the opposite: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29795404/783119

Comment: You're right... I couldn't find that question.... should I delete mine?

Comment: Up to you. I personally see no strong reason why -- simply because it may help finding the answer for other people who use similar keywords sequence in their search. It's not always that you can come up with "align array on value" or similar kind of keywords. Usually it's more general "how to align an array in a desired way"...

Comment: True... let's keep it then...